# NavigationBar not displaying properling when pushViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

The problem is pretty simple to understand with pictures. 
I have a UINavigationController that allow the user to switch between to views.

The first view contains a search bar and a table view like so :[image]

The second is a basic view where information about the cell are display

When I click on the search bar, the navigation controller gets hidden and the search bar is now at the top.

Now, if I click on a cell, it goes to the second views, but the navigation bar is first hidden like below :

[image]

And then, it automatically appears like that :

[image]

I have tried a couple of things like show the navigation bar before pushing the next view controller but it is quite ugly..
Does anyone know how to have the show the navigation bar directly on the second view (like in the contact application)?

**[UPDATE] : Code**

**AppDelegate.m** (I'm talking about navigationcontroller2)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    FirstViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    SecondViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

    viewController1.managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    viewController2.managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    viewController1.viewController2 = viewController2;

    UINavigationController *navigationcontroller1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
    [navigationcontroller1.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    UINavigationController *navigationcontroller2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
    [navigationcontroller2.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationcontroller1, navigationcontroller2, nil];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

**FirstView.m**

```
- (void) searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (!noResultsToDisplay) {
        PinDetailsViewController *pinDetailsViewController = [[PinDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PinDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];
        NSManagedObject *managedObject = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        Pin *pin = (Pin *) managedObject;

        [self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Pins"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:pinDetailsViewController animated:YES];
        [pinDetailsViewController updateWithPin:pin];
    }
}
```

If you need anything else, just ask but I think it's all there.

Comment: Please post some code. Otherwise it's very difficult to see where the problem is.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to use this code in each viewcontroller.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];

}


- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];

}
```

Comment: I changed the whole layout of my application so I don't use it anymore, but it works like a charm. Hope it's gonna help other people. Thank you.

Comment: It helps me in from a headache in December, 2015! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Before you push the new view controller, you should unhide the navigation bar:

`[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];`

Comment: If you read my post again, you'll notice I've already tried that. It works but it's ugly. I would like the same behavior as in the Contact application.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with the position of my navbar. Mine was moving up behind the status bar, and I fixed the issue by manually setting the navbar frame:

```
-(void)adjustNavBarOrigin
{
    CGRect r = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
    r.origin = CGPointMake(0, 20);  // 20 is the height of the status bar
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = r;   
}
```

I had to call this method in a number of places, including viewWillAppear: and didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:, but it worked a treat :)

Answer (score 0):

Hiding the UINavigationBar can disturb the properties sometimes. Try using the property `alpha` instead of `hidden`.